# Usage of 「なり」 with nouns

Tags: grammar

What is なり means in the following sentence, as far as I can guess it's close to the second one [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/165329/m1u/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A/).

> 「少なくとも、いきなり挑戦される可能性は低い。その間に、戦う準備なり勝つ方法を考えていかないといけないが…」

Some sort of translation:

> "At the very least, the possibility of us being challenged is low. In
>   ths time period we have to think about **fight preparations and the
>   way to win**."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> as far as I can guess it's close to the second one here.
>
> > ［副助］名詞、名詞に準じる語、副詞、活用語の終止形、助詞などに付く。それ以外にも適当なものがあるという気持ちを含めて、ある事柄を例示的に示す意を表す。…でも。「彼に―相談したらいい」「電話―してください」

Maybe you're right.

なり in this case describes that there's an available way you can choose directly, but it seems that you are still able to choose another way.

- 「彼になり相談したらいい」 could be "You may ask him (or another person.)"
- 「電話なりしてください」 could be "Call me (or use another way to communicate with me)."

> (Your translation)
> we have to think about fight preparations and the way to win.

This なり doesn't mean "and". If I translated this phrase, it would be...

> we have to think about the way to win **such as** fight preparation.

Because なり denotes a specific example as I explained above.

---

FYI, if this phrase contained two なり like this:

> 戦う準備なり勝つ方法 **なり** を考えていかないといけないが…

This should be translated as

> we have to think about fight preparations **or** the way to win (or other things we need).

Comment: Thank you very, it seems I misunderstood the grammar explanation.